# true/false logic in exclusive gateway - camunda bpmn

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I am working on **Generated Task Forms**, I am trying to apply **true/false** logic in exclusive gateway. If true, end process. If false, redirect to data correction task.

```
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_180tuqy" name="Yes" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway_1gplnrv" targetRef="EndEvent_16krmz0">
  <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">${approved}</bpmn:conditionExpression>
</bpmn:sequenceFlow>
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1" name="No" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway_1gplnrv" targetRef="stock_management">
  <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">${!approved}</bpmn:conditionExpression>
</bpmn:sequenceFlow>
```

here ${approved} -> **approved** is the id of the boolean form fied, but it does not work.

what I need to mention in **bpmn:conditionExpression**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

I´d like to ask if you write the BPMN-File yourself? Because there´s also a tool for it:

https://camunda.org/bpmn/tool/

Second:

On first sight I can´t see where there would be a problem. It looks ok to me. Often Camunda has problems with variables in conditions. 

Try to write `${approved == true}` instead of `${approved}` and `${approved == false}` instead of `${!approved}`. If this doen´t work, maybe the problem lies elsewhere.

EDIT:

May you please explain what exactly happens, when quote "it does not work"?